# How do you correctly use React.lazy() in Typescript to import a react component with a generic type parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

(repro at https://github.com/codingismy11to7/lazy-component-typing)

I'm guessing this is an issue with `@types/react` and the `LazyExoticComponent` definition...

When using `React.lazy()` on a component with a type parameter, Typescript can no longer compile
the project.

Given the component:

```
import React from "react";

export interface Props<T> {
  value: T;
  valueCallback: (t: T) => void;
}

export default function TypedComponent<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{`${props.value}`}</div>
      <button onClick={() => props.valueCallback(props.value)}>click</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

This compiles:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import TypedComponent from "./TypedComponent";

export default function StrictComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("blah");

  return (
    <TypedComponent value={state} valueCallback={setState}/>
  );
}
```

while this does not:

```
import React, {lazy, useState} from "react";
const TypedComponent = lazy(() => import("./TypedComponent"));

export default function LazyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("blah");

  return (
    <TypedComponent value={state} valueCallback={setState}/>
  );
}
```

```
TypeScript error in D:/dev/lazy-component-typing/src/LazyComponent.tsx(9,35):
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '(t: unknown) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 't' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string) => string'.  TS2322

     7 | 
     8 |   return (
  >  9 |     <TypedComponent value={state} valueCallback={setState}/>
       |                                   ^
    10 |   );
    11 | }
    12 |
```

Comment: Did you find a proper solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Not the ideal solution, but I was able to achieve this by exporting the component's type, and then using that to cast the result of React.lazy

```
export type TypedComponentType = typeof TypedComponent;
```

And then

```
import type { TypeComponent } from './TypedComponent';
const TypedComponent = lazy(() => import("./TypedComponent")) as TypedComponentType;
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I'd just cast it to `typeof TypedComponent` instead of creating new type just for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:
You can override `React.lazy` type definition to support generics.

react.d.ts:

```
declare namespace React {
  function lazy<T extends ComponentType<any>>(
    factory: () => Promise<{ default: T }>,
  ): T;
}
```

Explanation: Original `React.lazy` declaration looks like this:

```
function lazy<T extends ComponentType<any>>(
  factory: () => Promise<{ default: T }>
): LazyExoticComponent<T>;
```

It returns `LazyExoticComponent` type, which is superset of `ExoticComponent`. Unfortunately, this interface is written in way which don't support generics. However, according to [comment above the interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/dc09e01c627597d4b412f03b1aa126dab3fa0049/types/react/index.d.ts#L311), it is meant only for internal distinction between "regular" and other components, like results of `lazy` and `memo` calls; in JSX syntax there's no difference between this `ExoticComponent` and `Component`. That's why we can safely omit `LaxyExoticComponent` type in our custom override and make use of generics.

Answer (score -4):

TSX doesn't seem to play well with type arguments in props.

You should set a default type param value, such as `any`, but that will just assume your types are always `any` when using the component, which might not be exactly what you want:

```
export interface Props<T = any> {
  value: T;
  valueCallback: (t: T) => void;
}

// ...

// `valueCallback` will pass an explicit `any`
<TypedComponent value={value} valueCallback={setState} />
```

You could try copying it with the valid extended type, and then using that, e.g.:

```
import { Props as TCProps } from './TypedComponent'
const StronglyTypedComponent: React.Component<TCProps<string>> = TypedComponent

// ...

// correctly typed, but more verbal
<StronglyTypedComponent value={value} valueCallback={setState} />
```

Comment: TSX handles my type arguments fine in cases like what you wrote, the problem only happens when combined with `React.lazy()`